# Prove that the class of well-founded sets is a proper class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does anyone have an "elementary" proof of the following claim:

> If $A$ is a class such that
>   $$(*)\qquad\forall x(x\subseteq A\to x\in A),$$ then $A$ is a proper class, i.e. $\forall y\ y\ne A$.

The reason that the title refers to well-founded sets is that if we define the standard cumulative hierarchy $V_\alpha=\bigcup_{\delta<\alpha}{\cal P}(V_\delta)$ with ${\rm WF}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in{\sf On}}V_\alpha$, then it can be proven that $A\supseteq{\rm WF}$ if $A$ satisfies $(*)$. Now I know a proof of the claim using this and ${\rm WF}\supseteq{\sf On}$, together with the Burali-Forti paradox and the subset axiom, but that seems a bit contrived. I feel like there should be a simple proof by contradiction in the vein of Russel's paradox or the Burali-Forti paradox. (Don't assume regularity; it is not necessary, but the proof is trivial assuming it, because any set satisfying $(*)$ is an element of itself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition given allows us to directly imitate Russell’s paradox.

Suppose $A$ were a set.  Then take $R := \{x \in A\ |\ x \notin x \}$; $R$ is a set by the Separation axiom, and certainly $R \subseteq A$, so $R \in A$ by hypothesis.  But now, just as in Russell’s paradox, $R \in R \Leftrightarrow R \notin R$; contradiction.

Comment: This is nice.  I was going to do it by using $\mathcal{P}(A) \subset A$ and Cantor's theorem, but it boils down to this, which is simpler.

Comment: Well, that was easy. I can't believe I didn't see that myself. This makes me think that this is the "correct" generalization of Russell's paradox, in the sense that this is the only property of $V$ used in the proof that Russell's class is not a set.

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem.** For every set $a$ there is a set $b\subseteq a$ such that $b\notin a$.

**Proof.** Let $b=\{x\in a:x\notin x\}$.

Comment: Even easy questions may have multiple good answers that differ in nontrivial ways, so it's still worth a try.  Also, this answer is even clearer than the other answer regarding the general statement being proved.

Comment: I think in this case it's fine to leave it, because (1) it's not exactly the same, and (2) people can see from looking at the timestamp that it was posted at about the same time and so is not just a "me too" answer.